# Does every smooth hypersurface in CP^n admit a Kahler-Einstein metric

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Is it a solved problem whether every smooth hypersurface X in CP^n admits a Kaehler-Einstein metric?  Of course the c_1<0 and c_1 =0 cases are old, and every Fermat hypersurface does.  It seems that existing knowledge implies they all do.

For example they are all Chow-Mumford stable.  G. Tian then proved that the K-energy is proper, so if there are no hol. vector fields there is a K-E metric.

I'm reading someone's paper that has a result that gives another proof.  But I'm not sure if this paper is correct yet.

Comment: What is the paper? I would be surprised if it was already known that all hypersurfaces have a KE metric (at least this would be a very fresh result). On the other hand the following paper : http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/0810/0810.1473v1.pdf together with Yau Tian Donladson conjecture would suggest that one should expect that the metric should exist.

Comment: I don't think the paper that inspired me is posted on the arXiv yet.  